# select any folder as startfolder for browsing (win32gui,win32com, SHGetFolderLocation)

Tags: python, directory, win32com, win32gui

I want to start with a folder e.g. C:\test
**instead of** any of the **predefined CSIDL_*** folders.
How can I achieve that?

```
    ''' python 3.6.2 '''

    import os
    import win32gui
    from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

    myfolder_pidl = shell.SHGetFolderLocation (0, shellcon.CSIDL_DESKTOP, 0, 0)

    pidl, display_name, image_list = shell.SHBrowseForFolder (
      win32gui.GetDesktopWindow (),
      myfolder_pidl,
      "Select a file or folder",
      0x00014050, #shellcon.BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES and some more
      None,
      None
    )

    if (pidl, display_name, image_list) == (None, None, None):
        print ('Nothing selected')
    else:
        my_path = shell.SHGetPathFromIDList (pidl)

    file_to_process = my_path.decode()

    ''' continue processing file_to_process
    '''
```

Comment: I wonder why this has been downvoted ... (after 34 months)

Comment: Agreed!  The [documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/shell__SHBrowseForFolder_meth.html) is extremely unintuitive, the [provided example](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/com/win32comext/shell/demos/browse_for_folder.py) doesn't show how to do this, and there are no other obvious Google results for this.  You have my +1.

Comment: @Alex thx ... Jeff's answer was really helpful ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get a PIDL for the desired folder.

```
myfolder_pidl = shell.SHParseDisplayName(u"C:\test", 0)[0]
```

then pass that into `SHBrowseForFolder`